# Problem with sending messages to telegram bot with php

Tags: php, iis-7

So the problem is : iam trying to send a message with php code to telegram bot the code I use

```
`<?php
// Telegram function which you can call
function telegram($msg) {
        global $telegrambot,$telegramchatid;
        $url='https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$telegrambot.'/sendMessage';$data=array('chat_id'=>$telegramchatid,'text'=>$msg);
        $options=array('http'=>array('method'=>'POST','header'=>"Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",'content'=>http_build_query($data),),);
        $context=stream_context_create($options);
        $result=file_get_contents($url,false,$context);
        return $result;
}

// Set your Bot ID and Chat ID.
$telegrambot='7345345735:agADFsfjdfhSGTYJdfafhksdsdrQ';
$telegramchatid=374659345;

// Function call with your own text or variable
telegram ("Here is your message!!");
?>`
```

When I run php code nothing happen and no message is received in bot

Iam using IIS on windows server 2019

Comment: (1)Please confirm whether BOT is added to the telegram group    (2) Print the result returned by file_get_contents

Comment: Not added to any group
And the result is blank on web and no.message on telegram